# FB.provide is not a function

Tags: facebook

I'm developing a WordPress plugin to show above or bottom the posts Facebook like and send buttons.

Unfortunately when is also activated a plugin for Facebook share button there is a Javascript error (FB.provide is not a function) and like and send buttons don't appear.

For example this happens in this page: http://www.pasqualepuzio.it/2011/04/plugin-facebook-like-and-send-button/

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ´ve faced the same problem and it happens if you add the script twice on the site (http://connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/all.js)

Comment: it is funny, I have this only once in my page (not twice) and it is still showing the error commented by OP.

Answer (score 2):

I understood that part that we cant have all.js twice but I want to have Facebook Share Button and Facebook Like Button.

According to Docs, I need to include these two JS Files.
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share

Now, If I include both Firebug will give me same error "FB.provide is not a function". If I remove either of them then Like or Share button wont work.

I can do iFrame version but I have HTML Encoding issues with iFrame Version. I am programmatic generating HTML Response.

Any idea, how to approach?

Comment: They deprecated share in favor of like.

Comment: The Share button opens up a window pointing to:
'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php'
with the querystring: '?u=[url-to-share]&src=sp',
so I think we (=everyone who still wants to have a 'share' button) can simply implement it manually. Does anybody know what is the 'src=sp' for?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this: instead of placing the javascript Fb.Share within the same page where you are loading the Javascript SDK, use an Iframe with the first and set it in the second.